# Sortablejs - how can exclude element from sorting

Tags: sortablejs

Using `Sortable.js` I'm trying to make only `Collapsible elements` change their order so if I move element #1 in the place of element #2 they don't affect the green line between them. I've tried `filter` option but it just blocks my green line element to be draggable but I can put any element in place of it which I want to block. Is it possible to make with library like that?

[image]

Comment: A little late but I had similar issue that was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610468/559079). In your case it may still not work -- I would recommend using [SortableJS Swap Plugin](http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#swap) instead

Answer (score 1):

Since I mentioned using swap, here's a demo that may work (I know it's late but for the record)

```js
Sortable.create(list, {
  draggable: ".list-group-item",
  filter: ".divider",
  swap: true,
  swapClass: "highlight",
  animation: 150,

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #f9c7c8 !important;
}

.divider {
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  width: 3px;
  margin-left: 50%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/SortableJS/Sortable/master/Sortable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="list" class="list-group">
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```