# SortableJS - can't exclude item from being draggable and sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, sortablejs

I've already submitted an [issue here](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/issues/2014) but just wanted to check if you can solve this faster here.

Trying to exclude an item from being draggable works but not from being sortable -- the problem is that other elements can be placed behind it.

[SortableJS Docs](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#options) don't seem to have exclude.

Here's the expected behavior using jQuery UI:

```js
//jQuery UI
$("#demo .sortable").sortable({
    items: "li:not(.exclude)",
    cancel: "li.exclude"
});
$("#demo .sortable").disableSelection();

$('.add-new').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().clone().insertBefore(this);
});
```

```css
h1{ font-size: 1em; margin:1em}
.sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 260px; overflow:auto; }
.sortable li { background:lightgray; text-align:center; float:left; width:50px; height:50px; margin:0.2em; padding: 0.2em; cursor:move; }
.sortable li.add-new{cursor:default; color:#959595; opacity:0.8; background: white; outline:2px dotted gray}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h1>jQuery UI</h1>
<div id="demo">
    <ul class="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default add-new exclude"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add New Item</li>
    </ul>
    
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

*Notice that you can never place an item after the last "Add New Item".*
[This is another example](https://www.airpartsco.com/airparts_homepage/development-bundle/demos/sortable/items.html) using jQuery UI that makes distinction between sortable and drop target and can disable it either one.

What I've tried so far with SortableJS:

```js
// SortableJS

let mySortable = $("#demo2 .sortable").sortable({
  draggable: "li:not(.exclude)",
  animation: 250,
  forceFallback: true,
  removeCloneOnHide: true,
  touchStartThreshold: 10,

  onMove: function(evt) {
    //doesn't work
    //console.log ($(evt.dragged).index(),$('.exclude').index());
    //return $(evt.dragged).is(':last-child') ? false : true; 
  },

  onEnd: function(evt) {
    var itemEl = evt.item; // dragged HTMLElement
    if (!$('.exclude').is(':last-child')) {
      // Somewhat works but is super hacky and visually bad.
      //$('.exclude').appendTo($('.exclude').parent());  
    }
  }
});


$('.add-new').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().clone().insertBefore(this);
});
```

```css
h1{ font-size: 1em; margin:1em}
.sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 260px; overflow:auto; }
.sortable li { background:lightgray; text-align:center; float:left; width:50px; height:50px; margin:0.2em; padding: 0.2em; cursor:move; }
.sortable li.add-new{cursor:default; color:#959595; opacity:0.8; background: white; outline:2px dotted gray}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-sortablejs@latest/jquery-sortable.js"></script>



<h1>SortableJS</h1>
<div id="demo2">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li draggable="false" droppable="false" class="ui-state-default add-new exclude"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add New Item</li>
  </ul>

</div>
<!-- End demo -->
```

I don't want to take the "Add New Item" out of the sortable div or `position:absolute` it
Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check documentation there is one option [filter: ".ignore-elements"](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#options) you can use this to ignore elements which you do not want to be draggable . Then , check if the related target element doesn't have *exclude* class depending on this return true or false to cancel event.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
let mySortable = $("#demo2 .sortable").sortable({
  animation: 250,
  forceFallback: true,
  removeCloneOnHide: true,
  touchStartThreshold: 10,
  filter: ".exclude", //use this
  onMove: function(evt) {
    return evt.related.className.indexOf('exclude') === -1; //and this
  }
});


$('.add-new').click(function() {
  $(this).prev().clone().insertBefore(this);
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em
}

.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 260px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sortable li {
  background: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  cursor: move;
}

.sortable li.add-new {
  cursor: default;
  color: #959595;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: white;
  outline: 2px dotted gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-sortablejs@latest/jquery-sortable.js"></script>



<h1>SortableJS</h1>
<div id="demo2">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li draggable="false" droppable="false" class="ui-state-default add-new exclude"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>Add New Item</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```